# How do I remove an item from a nested array in Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to remove the type 'A' from the capital. How do I do it? Any code example will be appreciated. I am working on a react project.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no *nested* array in the document you shared. In that case you can use the `arrayRemove` operator to [remove a unique item from the array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
const cityRef = doc(db, "cities", "capital");

await updateDoc(cityRef, {
    region: arrayRemove({ type: "A" })
});
```

A few things to note here:

- You can to pass the entire array item to the `arrayRemove` operator, as it only removes array items that exactly and completely match the value you pass.
- The `arrayRemove` operations removes all items that match. So if you have multiple `{ type: "A" }` items in the array, all will be removed.
- This operation can only work on an array field at a known path, it cannot work on an array that is nested under another array.

If your use-case can't satisfy any of the requirements above, the way to remove the item would be to:

1. Load the document and get the array from it.
2. Update the array in your application code.
3. Write the entire top-level array back to the database.

Comment: what if it's like this: region's type is map, there are two more maps. one is country and the other is city. city have two arrays. one is light and another one is heavy. if i want to remove an item from heavy array without interrupting the light array and the country (map), how do I do so? I have added one more image of the db and updated the question. Any suggestion and help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't change your question after we've addressed the initial problem. If you have another problem now that this one is solved, post a new question. But you might want to look at this doc on updating nested fields before doing so: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

Comment: sure. thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to get the doc and clone properties into temporary object
2. you modify your temp object (remove item form region array)
3. update original doc with temp object

> a cleanest way is to do that throught a firestore/transaction

a small example to have a small approach

```js
const doc = await cityRef('cities/capital').get()
const temp =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data()))
temp.region = temp.region.filter(item => item.type !== 'A')
await cityRef('cities/capital').update(temp)
```

Comment: what if it's like this: region's type is map, there are two more maps. one is country and the other is city. city have two arrays. one is light and another one is heavy. if i want to remove an item from heavy array without interrupting the light array and the country (map), how do I do so? I have added one more image of the db and updated the question. Any suggestion and help will be much appreciated.